# Issue with Oracle select query 2

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table report of production, and I want to bridge between minus value and positive value on `QTY` field.

I want to make a new column with positive value, and another column with negative value selected from the `QTY` field.

```
    mtl_trx  qty      uom
1   20       1230     KG           
2   39       950      KG         
3   45       100      LBR       
4   91       250      KG            
5   118     -500      KG            
6   125     -284      KG
7   137     -120      KG     
8   143     -80       KG
```

Comment: Hello, it's not massively clear what you are asking - can you format the question a little better so it is clear which data is in which column and also show the expected output?

Comment: What's a "*ur advice*"?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to select two columns, one showing the positiv values, one the negative ones? Use a case construct to decide whether to show a value or not.

```
select mtl_trx, qty, uom,
  case when qty > 0 then qty end as qty_pos,
  case when qty < 0 then qty end as qty_neg
from mytable;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select mtl_trx, qty, uom, 
case when qty > 0 then qty  else 0 end as positive, 
case when qty < 0 then qty else 0 end as negative
from production;
```